# Where can I find actual link to Wordpress admin ( wp-admin ), when changed by plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I have changed ( probably ) my `wp-admin` url with https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-wp-admin-login/ plugin. And forgot the permalink I've set. Now I can't access admin panel.

If this information stored somewhere in DB or in files? apache/nginx configuration etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's stored in the options table in the DB. the option name is `rwl_page`